# Как грамотно проверить нашлась ли запись в базе данных

Tags: php, mysql

Есть запрос

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ?='?'");
$row = $result->fetch_array();
```

Больше ничего нет и быть не может

```
if($row !== NULL) ?
if(!empty($row)) ?
if($row) ?
if(isset($row)) ?
```

Уже много лет мучает этот вопрос

Comment: А сами найденные записи нужны в этом месте или нет? Просто если не нужны, то лучше проверять через `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` и смотреть, что вернулся `0`. Зачем гонять сами записи, если проверяется только факт, что они есть.

Comment: Нужны, я специально подметил, что больше кода никакого, только проверка $row

Comment: И много лет не можешь заглянуть в мануал https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-array-returnvalues

Comment: Я не профи, поэтому могу многое не учитывать и хотел уточнить. gettype($row) возвращает NULL, но мало ли...

Comment: Тем не менее, на вопрос так никто ответить конкретно и не смог )

Comment: Я лично на `PHP` последний раз писал 25 лет назад, пусть кто-нибудь другой отвечает %)